# HQL return ISO Timestamp

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, timestamp, hiveql

We have Hive table something like below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF not EXISTS xxxx
(
    `Timestamp` Timestamp
)
ROW format serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('timestamp.formats'="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z',yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z',yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS'Z'")
```

and json data as follows:

```
{.....,"TimeStamp":"2016-01-26T13:50:00.422Z",....}
```

Thanks to `SERDEPROPERTIES` and `timestamp.formats` hive is able to process this json data into Timestamp format. This is great because we can work with the string timestamp as it was [Timestamp](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-TimestampstimestampTimestamps) so we can use Timestamp's UDFs.

But we would like to also deserialize this data into ISO time format - back to the original one -`"2016-01-26T13:50:00.422Z"`. With that said we need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM xxx
```

and get time in ISO format:

```
2016-01-26T13:50:00.422Z
```

We would like to avoid using `someUDF(Timestamp)` in `HQL` b/c we need to return all fields (using asterix for that). Is it even possible to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

This will convert epoch back to iso format but some accuracy in the fractional seconds is lost.  Hope it helps. Thanks.

```
Query:  select concat(regexp_replace(cast(from_unixtime(cast(946713612 as bigint), 
'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as string),' ','T'),'Z');

Result: 2000-01-01T03:00:12.000Z
```

Comment: thanks but as i mentioned we dont want to use udf or “manual” postprocessing like in your answer

Comment: When you create the table and load the data, create another column (say timestamp_str) then copy the values with string format. Hive doesn't have date ISO format to start with. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but we dont want to use a new column for this. We just need to say to hive -> lets return Timestamp type in this format. Something like with `SERDEPROPERTIES` where we are saying to hive -> lets parse this timestamp to your timestamp type so you are able to do manipulation with time. So same thing but reversed it's what we need. Without any workaround like new columns or udfs. Something in the background like `SERDEPROPERTIES ('timestamp.formats`